# create xml file from sql script

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

how to Generate xml file in sql server 2005 using tsql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored proc exec DBName.dbo.Table
is

```
select * from table for xml path 
SET @SQL= 'bcp "exec DBName.dbo.Table" queryout c:\myfile.xml -w -r -t -SServerName -T'
EXEC Master..xp_CmdShell @SQL
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Select Emp_Id,Emp_Name from tblEmployee Where Emp_Id < 3
For XML AUTO,ELEMENTS
--For XML [MODE],ELEMENTS
```

#### MODE

AUTO, RAW, EXPLICIT

#### Result [AUTO]

```
<tblEmployee>
 <Emp_Id>1</Emp_Id>
 <Emp_Name>AAA</Emp_Name>
</tblEmployee>
<tblEmployee>
 <Emp_Id>2</Emp_Id>
 <Emp_Name>BBB</Emp_Name>
</tblEmployee>
```

#### Result [RAW]

Above Xml with Instead of `<tblEmployee>` here..... `<ROW>` and `</tblEmployee>` is `</ROW>`